# Is it possible to embed two webcam streams on one Html page from one or more cameras.

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

Im trying to Embed two webcam streams on one HTML page.

I am use to a get user media script that I got from this site https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm

It works fine for one steam but when I try to make two different video streams on the same page it doesn't work.

I have tried making a div tag with a grid in it and putting one video element in each cell. This results in only one stream.

Here is my most recent try

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
  <meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
  <meta content="Display Webcam Stream" name="title">
  <title>Display Webcam Stream</title>
  
  <style>
    #container {
      margin: 0px auto;
      width: 500px;
      height: 375px;
      border: 10px #333 solid;
    }
    #videoElement {
      width: 500px;
      height: 375px;
      background-color: #666;
    }
    #container2 {
      margin: 0px auto;
      width: 500px;
      height: 375px;
      border: 10px #333 solid;
    }
    #videoElement2 {
      width: 500px;
      height: 375px;
      background-color: #666;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="">
  <div id="container">
    
    <video autoplay id="videoElement">
      
    </video>
  </div>

  <div id="container2">
    
    <video2 autoplay="true" id="videoElement2">
      
    </video2>
  </div>

  <script>
    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

     
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia; 
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {          
      navigator.getUserMedia({
        video: true
      }, handleVideo, videoError);
    } 

    function handleVideo(stream) {    
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } 

    function videoError(e) {     // do something
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Your script references `videoElement` but not `videoElement2`...

Comment: i'm not not saying you can't, but it would be news and slightly surprising to me if you could. last i heard, you can barely select one camera or the other...

Comment: @jball how can I correct this?

Comment: how do you select the second camera?

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa one has to be attached. when the browser asks you for access to the camera there is a drop down, where you can select the camera. it works best with Firefox.

Comment: @AlexGolshani sorry, im a little confused, are you using 2 cameras or 1 camera locally and getting the other camera via stream from another place?

Comment: You only call `getUserMedia` once and you never reference `videoElement2`... how do you expect this to work?

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa the other camera is plugged in to the computer via usb.

Comment: @jib It seams like you know what the problem is. Can you explain what I', doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You tell a `video` element which `stream` to play by setting its `src` property.

Basically you need to duplicate all the code supporting `videoElement` here, not just its creation.

One problem you'll run into is that many browsers frown on calling `getUserMedia` twice at the same time (before the previous asynchronous call has completed), because this overwhelms users with multiple prompts at once. To work around this, put the second call to `getUserMedia` inside `handleVideo`, to only bother the user with one prompt at a time.

The third problem you'll run into, is that only Firefox has built-in device selection in the permission prompt, so on Chrome you'll get the same camera twice.

To make this work on other browsers you'll need `enumerateDevices`. I've [answered that before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770656/918910).

Lastly, most smart phones are hardware limited and can't run both cameras at once.